# circos.heatmap(): Error in rowMeans(m) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r, data-visualization, circlize

I'm following the tutorial to make [circular plots in R](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/). Suppose I have this dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
    mat1 = rbind(cbind(matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = 1), nr = 50), 
                   matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = -1), nr = 50)),
                cbind(matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = -1), nr = 50), 
                   matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = 1), nr = 50))
                )
    rownames(mat1) = paste0("R", 1:100)
    colnames(mat1) = paste0("C", 1:10)
    mat1 = mat1[sample(100, 100), ] # randomly permute rows
    split = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE)
    split = factor(split, levels = letters[1:5])
```

I tried using `Heatmap` and it returns appropriately.

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
Heatmap(mat1, row_split = split)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyyB3.png)

However, when I try to use `circos.heatmap()`, it returns error:

```
library(circlize)
col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("blue", "white", "red"))
circos.heatmap(mat = mat1, split = split, col = col_fun1)
circos.heatmap(mat = mat1, col = col_fun1)
> Error in rowMeans(m) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

The matrix itself has a dimension of 100 x 10. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue with `CRAN` version, but it was rectified after installing the dev version

```
devtools::install_github("jokergoo/circlize")
```

-testing

```
> library(circlize)
========================================
circlize version 0.4.13
CRAN page: https://cran.r-project.org/package=circlize
Github page: https://github.com/jokergoo/circlize
Documentation: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/

If you use it in published research, please cite:
Gu, Z. circlize implements and enhances circular visualization
  in R. Bioinformatics 2014.

This message can be suppressed by:
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(circlize))
========================================

> col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("blue", "white", "red"))
> ?circos.heatmap
starting httpd help server ... done
> 
> set.seed(123)
> mat1 = rbind(cbind(matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = 1), nr = 50), 
+                    matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = -1), nr = 50)),
+              cbind(matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = -1), nr = 50), 
+                    matrix(rnorm(50*5, mean = 1), nr = 50))
+             )
> rownames(mat1) = paste0("R", 1:100)
> colnames(mat1) = paste0("C", 1:10)
> mat1 = mat1[sample(100, 100), ] # randomly permute rows
> split = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE)
> spilt = factor(split, levels = letters[1:5])
> col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("blue", "white", "red"))
> circos.heatmap(mat1, split = split, col = col_fun1)
> circos.clear()
```

-output

[image]